# Update DataSet-Adapter Linqy way from a list

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, dataadapter

Taking advantage of **Linq** trying to make a neater update code on the provided DataSet-Based approach :

The Code I'm trying is :

```
                ListProducts.ForEach( product =>
                {
                    DsProducts.TblProductsRow row = Ds1Products.TblProducts.First( p => p.Name == product.Name);
                    row.Price = Product.Price ;
                });

                Adapter.Update(Ds1Products, "TblProducts");
```

Not sure weather I needed **parameters** here or not, I haven't defined any yet.
Cause wanted to use the "**Typed**" facilities of it.
The Data Adapter is initialized and filled.

**Notes :**

1. It does not work right now , Gotten Error here : `"Sequence contains no matching element"`
2. Wanted to Replace the **foreach** with **`Linq's Select`** if possible

   ( Try it to be neat and **Linqy** as possible )
3. its in SQL CE (Shouldn't be a problem here on most cases)

Comment: LINQ isn't the answer to everything. If what you have works, why change it?

Comment: If you got the answer to this without Linq please provide it, For me it could be my preference and also based on my current training phase, I think it could be possible here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hopefully what you need:

```
var productRows = from p in ListProducts
                  join row in Ds1Products.Tables["TblProducts"].AsEnumerable()
                  on p.Name equals row.Field<String>("Name")
                  select new { NewPrice = p.Price, Row = row };
foreach(var productInfo in productRows)
{
    productInfo.Row.SetField<Double>("Price", productInfo.NewPrice);
}
```

---

**Edit**: Here's the strong typed DataSet way(almost identical):

```
var productRows = from p in ListProducts
                  join row in Ds1Products.TblProduct
                  on p.Name equals row.Name 
                  select new { NewPrice = p.Price, Row = row };
foreach (var productInfo in productRows)
{
    productInfo.Row.Price = productInfo.NewPrice;
}
Adapter.Update(Ds1Products, "TblProducts");
```

By the way, [`List.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is not Linq, it existed already in .NET 2.0 hence prior to Linq.

Comment: Hi Tim, About Linq side of the question I said that I agree with you and wanted to change to be more Linqy. Why row.Field ? Couldn't I use any advantages of StronglyTyped Datasets ?

Comment: @Sypress: You can use typed datasets, but it's difficult for me to use them in the sample code, so i've provided a solution that works for typed and non-typed DataSets.

Comment: really thanks, these are valuable for me. I'm putting them into work.

Comment: please give me some minutes, will back

Comment: @Sypress: Only just edited the answer since you wanted to change the price, not the name :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13794/discussion-between-sypress-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 1):

There error you're getting is likely because of this line:

```
DsProducts.TblProductsRow row = 
    Ds1Products.TblProducts.First( p => p.Name == product.Name);
```

If a particular product name does not exist it will throw a "Sequence contains no matching element" exception. You can use `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first if any, or null.

Comment: How can I observe this, cause I'm sure everything in theList are exactly in the Database also. anything else should be correct you mean ?